# Opera blocked by OSX 10.8.5

Tags: macos, opera

Currently I am on OSX 10.8.5, I don't want to upgrade for multiple reasons. 
Yesterday out of the blue, the OS stops running after rebooting the machine and tells me I cannot use Opera anymore unless I update to OSX 10.9

I started by downloading older versions of Opera (Currently on 42, downloaded each version back to 37) and in every download get the same install OS X 10.9 message.

Any idea anybody? Thanks for the support.

**Note**: Upgrading to a later version of macOS is not an option in this case - please do not suggest this as a solution.

Comment: *the OS stops running after rebooting the machine and tells me I cannot use Opera anymore*  -- it feels like there's something missing here... it's implausible that an old browser would prevent OS X from booting.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I would encourage you to edit out the "don't bother". We operate on three simple ideas. **Anyone can ask / answer. Everyone gets to vote if an answer or question is good/useful. Only the asker can put a check mark.** _Worst case, someone answers - Upgrade and you graciously thank them for their help and explain you'll reserve your checkmark in case you can keep 10.8 running and not have to upgrade._

Answer (score 3):

You could install 10.8.5 clean on an external drive and just install the opera version you hope to use and test in a clean os. If that fails, you’ll know the program opera had a timer of sorts and can pursue disabling or modifying opera.

If it works, you can then migrate all your settings / apps / data (except opera) to the new os and test. Then restore that image over the broken internal install.

Splitting the troubleshooting up will save you time isolating and testing without risking your current setup that you wish to remain without an upgrade for reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough the process of downgrading Opera stops only when you reach version 37 (from 42) which by the way doesn't feature a VPN.

Alternatively, you could just re-install OSX 10.8.5 on an external HD (or a partition of the same HD) and see if Opera 42 is still not working.